# Delete tags from an XML file via batch

Tags: xml, batch-file

I need to remove `<batchRequest>` and `</batchRequest>` from my XML file in a batch file.

Is it possible?

My current file:

```
<batchRequest><sid sid="100000000" test="false" ></sid>
</batchRequest>
<batchRequest><sid sid="100000000" test="false" ></sid>
</batchRequest>
```

And I need this:

```
<sid sid="100000000" test="false" ></sid>
<sid sid="100000000" test="false" ></sid>
```

I'm stuck on this setting

```
set str=!str:<batchRequest>=!
```

If I use

```
set str=!str:batchRequest=!
```

It works, but isn't what I need.

My code so far:

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

For /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (_1000_1008603__30122015_153242_all.xml) do (
Set str=%%a
set str=!str:<batchRequest>=!
echo !str!>>_1000_1008603__30122015_153242_all_NEW.xml
)
```

Comment: The answer to your question is: **yes.** You should show your efforts and describe precisely where you are stuck...

Comment: The better answer to your question would be to load up an XML parser and manipulate the contents via the DOM, rather than scraping and hacking as text.  That way you aren't so dependent upon your XML files being formatted in any particular way (beautified, minified, Andre-fied, whatever), as long as it's valid XML.  I can show you some example code if you ask a new question.  But next time, phrase it as "How can I remove the `<batchRequest>` tags while keeping the child content by using DOM methods?"

Answer (score 1):

String operations like search-and-replace are not adequate for XML files, you will destroy your files that way sooner or later, most probably sooner.

Use a tool that is XML-aware, the most appropriate tool for your task is XSLT.

The following transformation removes `<batchRequest>` elements and leaves the rest of the document intact:

```
<!-- removeBatchRequest.xsl -->
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="batchRequest">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Use it with a command line XSL processor for batch support. The (dated but reliable) [msxsl.exe from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714) does the job perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try that.

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution that treats the XML to be modified as XML, rather than as complicated flat text.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I mentioned in my comment above.  Use the `MSXML.DOMDocument.6.0` COM object to parse the XML DOM and manipulate it using common DOM methods -- `.insertBefore` to relocate the inner nodes, then `.removeChild` to delete the unwanted and now empty tags.  If you've ever written JavaScript for a web page, those methods are probably already familiar.  Here's a batch + JScript hybrid example.  Save it with a .bat extension.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off & setlocal

for %%I in (*.xml) do cscript /nologo /e:Jscript "%~f0" "%%~I"

exit /b & @end // end batch; begin JScript hybrid chimera

var DOM = WSH.CreateObject('MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0'),
    XMLfile = WSH.Arguments(0);

DOM.load(XMLfile);

if (DOM.parseError.errorCode) {
    var e = DOM.parseError;
    WSH.StdErr.WriteLine('Error in ' + XMLfile + ' line ' + e.line + ' char '
        + e.linepos + ':\n' + e.reason + '\n' + e.srcText);
    WSH.Quit(1);
}

var bads = DOM.selectNodes('//batchRequest');

for (var i = bads.length; bad = bads[--i];) {
    while (bad.hasChildNodes())
        bad.parentNode.insertBefore(bad.firstChild, bad);
    bad.parentNode.removeChild(bad);
}

DOM.save(XMLfile);
```

A big advantage of this method is that all the necessary libraries and engines are already built into Windows.  There's no need to download and install any additional utilities.  It's also fast and provides more verbose error reporting if your XML has problems.   (A pure JScript or VBScript solution using `Scripting.FileSystemObject` could loop through files more quickly if you have many, but using a batch `for` loop keeps things a little simpler for this demonstration.)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q34534274.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
 FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=>" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
  IF "%%a"=="<batchRequest" ECHO %%b
 )
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q34534274.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Assumes your data is exactly as described.

Simply, tokenise each line using `>`. If the token matches the required token, regurgitate the rest of the line.